# How to obtain the same landscape with different road grids?

Tags: random, netlogo

I would like to get the same landscape at each time that I create a landscape in NetLogo. For this, I used

```
random-seed 0
create-landscape
```

It works when I keep the same configuration of roads (represented in white in the figure below) at each time that I create a landscape :

**Figure 1:**

[image]

However, when I change the configuration of roads, the location of blue, black, and red blocks is different (see figures below) by using `random-seed 0`.

**Figure 2:**

[image]

**Figure 3:**

[image]

For figures 2 and 3, I'm looking for a way to obtain the same location of blue, black, and red blocks than in Figure 1.
The roads have been built by using [Traffic Grid](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/TrafficGrid). To built my landscapes, I create, in the first time, the road grid and then, I randomly place the black, blue, and red blocks.

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something in your road network generation code affects the state of the random number generator. It can be lots of things. Even a simple `ask`, for example, makes use of randomness (to iterate through agents in random order). See [the section on random numbers in the programming guide](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#random).

There are probably a couple of different ways to handle this, but I would suggest using [`with-local-randomness`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with-local-randomness) to isolate the code that creates blocks and have it use its own random number generator. Something like:

```
to create-landscapes
  create-roads
  with-local-randomness [
    random-seed 0
    create-blocks
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much Nicolas. I am able to do it for the blue blocks by using `with-local-randomness` and `random-seed 0` but it doestn't work for the red and black blocks. I created these blocks from [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382612/how-to-color-patches-within-a-given-rectangle). As in this question, I created, for example, a function `create-black-patches` and `turn-black` for the black blocks. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Well, if you are "seeding" your blocks by picking `one-of patches`, it could very well be that the picked patches don't fall inside the same block anymore, given that your roads are placed differently. You would need to find a different way of picking your blocks. But that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make the landscape first.... then overlay the roads. This may also simplify the landscape code, since your code won't have to worry about overwriting roads.

Also, perhaps its time to graduate from only using color. Perhaps patches need a variable like "is-road?" and another like "land-use"... fill those variables separately. Then it's a only a matter of how you *display* the information, such as:

```
ask patches
[ ifelse is-road?
  [ set pcolor white ]
  [ set pcolor item land-use land-use-colors ]
]
```